# I dont understand why my code casts stack smashing

Tags: c, return-value, variable-assignment

I have this function in my code:

```
unsigned char **load_image(char *file_name)
{
    FILE *file;
    char ret[5],ret1[5],ret2[5],ret3[5],ret4[5];
    int height,width,max;
    int i,j,pom;
    unsigned char **loaded;

    file=fopen(file_name,"r");

   if( file == NULL )
       printf("didnt open \n");
   else 
       printf("opened! \n");

    fscanf(file,"%s %s %s %s %s",ret,ret1,ret2,ret3,ret4);
    fscanf(file,"%d",&width);
    fscanf(file,"%d",&height);
    fscanf(file,"%d",&max);

    loaded=alloc_uchar_array(height,width);

    for(i=0;i<height;i++)
        for(j=0;j<width;j++)
        {
            fscanf(file,"%u",&pom);
            loaded[i][j]=(unsigned char)pom;
        }

    fclose(file);

    return loaded;
}
```

I call it from main this way:

```
int main(int a)
{
    unsigned char **test_source;
    unsigned char **test_target;
    unsigned char pom_print;
    intensity_function *intensity_f;
    intensity_function *transformation;
    int height=1024;
    int width=1024;

    test_source=load_image("silma_05_442_1.pgm");
    test_target=load_image("silma_06_450_1.pgm");

    print_image(test_source,height,width,"priklad1_source.pgm");
    print_image(test_target,height,width,"priklad1_target.pgm");

    intensity_f=finite_volume_method(test_source,test_target,height,width);

    return 0;    
}
```

If i compile this code and debug it, I get this:

```
Starting program: /home/h1657/Work/bakalarka/a.out 
opened! 
*** stack smashing detected ***: /home/h1657/Work/bakalarka/a.out terminated

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7744bb9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007ffff7744bb9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x00007ffff7747fc8 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff7781e14 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=1, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff788e06b "*** %s ***: %s terminated\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3  0x00007ffff78197dc in __GI___fortify_fail (msg=<optimized out>, msg@entry=0x7ffff788e053 "stack smashing detected") at fortify_fail.c:37
#4  0x00007ffff7819780 in __stack_chk_fail () at stack_chk_fail.c:28
#5  0x0000000000407c9b in load_image (file_name=0x4089b2 "silma_05_442_1.pgm") at levelsetMethod.c:1380
```

I dont really understand what is causing the problem. There is probably some problem with the return or assignment of the return value to variable in main.

Anybody has some idea what am I doing wrong ?

**edit** 
Here is begginging of my pgm file:

```
P2
# Created by IrfanView
1024 1024
255
19 20 20 21 21 20 19 22 20 24 21 22 22 22 21 23 24
```

... and so on. There are no other coments inside. I just did debug print of image before returning **loaded** variable and it worked fine. Line 1380 is last line of function load_image which contains only `}`.

Comment: Run your program under valgrind, it will tell you where the problem is.

Comment: Which line is line number 1380? What's the start of the file which you scan? (Possibly the strings scanned with %s are too long).

Comment: As an aside, the error handling after the file canot be opened needs improvement ... just printing "I see an open knife!" and then running into it is suboptimal.

Comment: The PGM format starts with `P5`, and then *optional* comments may follow. You are assuming 5 very short(!) words before width and height. See [the PGM Format Specification](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html) for more.

Comment: SHow us the content of the filename `file_name`.

Comment: @Jongware I do not think the strings are optional (and they are not comments), but there are only 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pgm file spec (http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html) seems to indicate only the following strings in the file header:

1. magic number;
2. width;
3. height;
4. max gray value.

The rest of the file is binary. The fifth scanf into ret4 will try to write behind ret[4] unless the file has a black pixel early on (because the 0 byte for black would be interpreted as string terminator).

Two more remarks:

- The memory reserved for the strings will not suffice for large images
  (for a width of 10000 you'd need a ret1[6] already: 5 bytes for
  1,0,0,0,0 and a closing '\0').
- The parsing is not complete: Jongware was correct pointing out that
  pgm files may contain comments (marked by a hash sign).

Comment: I'm guessing this is where the OP is hardcoding stuff where he should not (and on top of that, possibly also reserving too little space for the comments).

Comment: I dont think there is problem with loading the image to that array.

Comment: Not the image; the ascii strings containing the size info.